# Probability of sum of independent random variables in different cases

Tags: probability

I have two independent random variables X ~ Uniform[0,1] and Y ~ Exponential(1) and I want to find $P(X+Y > a)$ for two cases: when $0 \leq a \leq 1$ and $a > 1$.

I've been able to draw the regions for both cases: for the case where $0 \leq a \leq 1$, the region is $\{(x,y) : 0 \leq x \leq 1, \ 0 \leq y \leq 1-x\}$ and for the case where $a > 1$, the region is $\{(x,y) : 0 \leq x \leq 1, \ 1-x \leq y \leq e^{-x}\}$.

What I haven't been able to figure out is P(X + Y > a) for each case. For example I've tried integrating over the region for $0 \leq a \leq 1$ where $X + Y > a$ as follows:

$$ \int_0^a \int_{a-x}^{1-x} e^{-y} \ dy \ dx  = 1 - e^{-a} + e^{-1} - a $$ However when I plot this it doesn't look correct as the probability that $ X + Y > 0$ isn't $1$.

For the case where $a > 1$, I'm stumped on what the integration bounds should be. Is there another approach that I should be taking other than trying to integrate over the regions for each case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know where $y <1-x$ came from in your calculation.

When $0 \leq a \leq 1$ the correct value is $\int_0^{a} \int_{a-x}^{\infty} e^{-y} dy dx+ \int_a^{1} \int _0^{\infty} e^{-y} dy dx$.

When $a>1$ we get $\int_0^{1}\int_{a-x}^{\infty} e^{-y} dydx$.

Comment: Thank you! I realised I incorrectly specified the upper bounds for y because I mistakenly thought that y was bounded by the pdf of Y (it's been a long day haha).

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 simpler methods to solve the problem:

- using convolution
- using conditioning

Let's use conditioning:
\begin{align}
P(X+Y>a)&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}P(X+Y>a|X=x)f_X(x)dx\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}P(X+Y>a|X=x)dx\\
&(\text{using independence of }X\text{ and }Y)\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}P(Y>a-x)dx\\
&(y=a-x)\\
&=\int_{a-1}^{a}P(Y>y)dy\\
\end{align}

Now for exponential random variable $Y\sim Exp(\lambda)$,
\begin{equation}
P(Y>y)=
\begin{cases}
e^{-\lambda y}, &y\geq 0\\
1, &y<0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

which give solutions for $0<a<1$ and $a>1$ cases.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Kavi helped point out a flaw in my logic for integrating the area of the regions, but I'll also give these methods a try and see if my answers match up.